# Are there any good templates for a JSON weather widget that I can customise the location on?

Tags: json, yahoo-api

What YQL query could I use to retrieve a 3 day weather forecast for Stoke-On-Trent (location code: 36340) - returning a json object

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking for tools, or templates aren't really a good fit for the site.  They're more open to opinions, and are too broad when it comes to all possibilities.  Consider reading [ask] and come back to [edit] if you're having a specific problem with any particular implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use different vendors you can check wonderground.

https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api

they have simple intuitive apis. For forecast you would particularly would be looking for https://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/forecast10day

Comment: Unfortunately, I was looking for a more source-code based answer or a guidance on a step by step process to achieve this